# Vue Data not getting updated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've the following on the mounted hook in my vue app.

```
let vm = this;
$("button[name='daterange']")
  .daterangepicker({
    ranges: vm.presets,
    opens: 'left',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    startDate: startDateValue,
    endDate: endDateValue
  }, function(start, end, label) { // cb for when dates are picked
    let filter = vm.$options.filters.date;
    vm.range = {
      start: start,
      end: end
    };
    console.log(vm.range);
    vm.$root.$emit('date.change', vm.range);
  });
```

and the data is as follows:

```
data: function() {
  return {
    currentRange: 'Last 7 Days',
    presets: {},
    range: {},
  }
},
```

For some reason, the watcher for `range` is not getting executed and I can't see the updated value in vue-dev-tool as well. But when I console log the value of `range`, it has the right data. This is the reason why I put the emit right below it. Can anyone help me find why the reactivity is not working here?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the usage instructions](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#usage), you set `format` inside a `locale` object. This works for me.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentRange: 'Last 7 Days',
    presets: {},
    range: {}
  },
  mounted() {
    let vm = this;
    $("[name='daterange']")
      .daterangepicker({
        ranges: vm.presets,
        opens: 'left',
        locale: {
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        },
        startDate: '2017-01-01',
        endDate: '2017-02-01'
      }, function(start, end, label) { // cb for when dates are picked
        vm.range = {
          start: start,
          end: end
        };
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button name='daterange'>Pick</button> {{range}}
</div>
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: This still not getting reactive.

Comment: The problem arises only on the first page load. If I switch tab to another component, it works.

Comment: Does my snippet work as you expect?  
Can you make a snippet that demonstrates your actual problem?